# Chrome console not running commands

Tags: console

Usually if you open the javascript console in Chrome, you can run something simple like:

```
console.log('Hello');
```

And it'll return:

```
Hello
```

My console just keeps returning `<-undefined` for everything. I've restarted Chrome. Is there a setting or something I'm missing?

Comment: Check your log level if set other than Verbose or Info.

Comment: It's set to Info.